# proceed after several await functions have resolved

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am trying to set some variables equal to the await result of a function, but I want the async functions to run concurrently.

my code:

```
async function track() {

  var track = await getTrack(urlParams.get('track'))

  var trackAnalysis = await getTrackAnalysis(urlParams.get('track'))

  var artists = await getArtists(artistIds)

  //then do something with all 3 variables after they have all been resolved

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them to run concurrently and they are actually asynchronous and return a promise that resolves with the appropriate value, then you can use `Promise.all()` to run them concurrently:

```
async function track() {
    let [track, trackAnalysis, artists] = await Promise.all([
        getTrack(urlParams.get('track')),
        getTrackAnalysis(urlParams.get('track')),
        getArtists(artistIds)
    ]);
    // do something with all 3 variables
}
```

Comment: oh missing parentheses after the second track. THANKS SO MUCH!